# Button click load data from url fragment

Tags: android, server, adapter

This is a project am trying to modify. The project is made in fragment. its an online market for buying and selling. the code below helps data to be fetched from server automatically when the App is lunched / opened. but i dont want it to load data Automatically but onlu load when a user press a button it will fetch the content from the server.  the METHOD_STREAM_GET below is for

public static final String METHOD_STREAM_GET = API_DOMAIN + "api/" + API_VERSION + "/method/stream.get" + API_FILE_EXTENSION;.

package ml.shopnet.market;

public class StreamFragment extends Fragment implements Constants, SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener 
{

```
private static final String STATE_LIST = "State Adapter Data";
private static final String STATE_LIST_2 = "State Adapter Data";

private static final int PROFILE_NEW_POST = 4;

RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
TextView mMessage;

SwipeRefreshLayout mItemsContainer;

FloatingActionButton mFabButton;

Button login;
GridView gridView;

private ArrayList<Item> itemsList;
private StreamListAdapter itemsAdapter;

private Parcelable mListState;

private int itemId = 0;
private int arrayLength = 0;
private Boolean loadingMore = false;
private Boolean viewMore = false;
private Boolean restore = false;

int pastVisiblesItems = 0, visibleItemCount = 0, totalItemCount = 0;

public StreamFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {

        itemsList = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(STATE_LIST_2);
        itemsAdapter = new StreamListAdapter(getActivity(), itemsList);

        restore = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("restore");
        itemId = savedInstanceState.getInt("itemId");

        viewMore = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("viewMore");

    } else {

        itemsList = new ArrayList<>();
        itemsAdapter = new StreamListAdapter(getActivity(), itemsList);

        restore = false;
        itemId = 0;
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_latest, container, false);
    mItemsContainer = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.container_items);
    mItemsContainer.setOnRefreshListener(this);

    mMessage = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.message);

    mFabButton = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fabButton);
    mFabButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_new);

    if (App.getInstance().getId() == 0) {

        mFabButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }






    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    final GridLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), Helper.getGridSpanCount(getActivity()));
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(Helper.getGridSpanCount(getActivity()), dpToPx(10), true));
    mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);

    mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy)
        {
            if(dy > 0) //check for scroll down
            {
                visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                pastVisiblesItems = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                if (!loadingMore)
                {
                    if ((visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount && (viewMore) && !(mItemsContainer.isRefreshing()))
                    {
                        loadingMore = true;
                        Log.e("...", "Last Item Wow !");

                        getItems();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(getActivity(), mRecyclerView, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

            Item i = (Item) itemsList.get(position);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ViewItemActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("itemId", i.getId());
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {
            // ...
        }
    }));

    mFabButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NewItemActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, STREAM_NEW_POST);
        }
    });

    if (itemsAdapter.getItemCount() == 0) {

        showMessage(getText(R.string.label_empty_list).toString());

    } else {

        hideMessage();
    }

    if (!restore) {

        showMessage(getText(R.string.msg_loading_2).toString());

        getItems();
    }

    return rootView;
}

static class RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

    public interface OnItemClickListener {

        void onItemClick(View view, int position);

        void onItemLongClick(View view, int position);
    }

    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, OnItemClickListener listener) {

        mListener = listener;

        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {

                View childView = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());

                if (childView != null && mListener != null) {

                    mListener.onItemLongClick(childView, recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {

        View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());

        if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {

            mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }
}

/**
 * RecyclerView item decoration - give equal margin around grid item
 */
public class GridSpacingItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    private int spanCount;
    private int spacing;
    private boolean includeEdge;

    public GridSpacingItemDecoration(int spanCount, int spacing, boolean includeEdge) {

        this.spanCount = spanCount;
        this.spacing = spacing;
        this.includeEdge = includeEdge;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {

        int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view); // item position
        int column = position % spanCount; // item column

        if (includeEdge) {

            outRect.left = spacing - column * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
            outRect.right = (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // (column + 1) * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)

            if (position < spanCount) { // top edge

                outRect.top = spacing;
            }

            outRect.bottom = spacing; // item bottom

        } else {

            outRect.left = column * spacing / spanCount; // column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
            outRect.right = spacing - (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - (column + 1) * ((1f /    spanCount) * spacing)

            if (position >= spanCount) {

                outRect.top = spacing; // item top
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Converting dp to pixel
 */
private int dpToPx(int dp) {

    Resources r = getResources();

    return Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, r.getDisplayMetrics()));
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putBoolean("viewMore", viewMore);

    outState.putBoolean("restore", true);
    outState.putInt("itemId", itemId);

    mListState = mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState();
    outState.putParcelable(STATE_LIST, mListState);

    outState.putParcelableArrayList(STATE_LIST_2, itemsList);
}

@Override
public void onRefresh() {

    if (App.getInstance().isConnected()) {

        itemId = 0;
        getItems();

    } else {

        mItemsContainer.setRefreshing(false);
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == STREAM_NEW_POST && resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK && null != data) {

        itemId = 0;
        getItems();

    } else if (requestCode == ITEM_EDIT && resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {

        int position = data.getIntExtra("position", 0);

        Item item = itemsList.get(position);

        item.setContent(data.getStringExtra("post"));
        item.setImgUrl(data.getStringExtra("imgUrl"));

        itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

public void showToast(String msg) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell_categories, parent, false);

        ImageView myimage= (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.img);

        TextView mytitle= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.category);

        myimage.setImageResource(image[position]);

        mytitle.setText(title[position]);


        return row;
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

public void getItems() {

    mItemsContainer.setRefreshing(true);

    CustomRequest jsonReq = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.POST, METHOD_STREAM_GET, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    if (!isAdded() || getActivity() == null) {

                        Log.e("ERROR", "StreamFragment Not Added to Activity");

                        return;
                    }

                    if (!loadingMore) {

                        itemsList.clear();
                    }

                    try {

                        arrayLength = 0;

                        if (!response.getBoolean("error")) {

                            itemId = response.getInt("itemId");

                            if (response.has("items")) {

                                JSONArray itemsArray = response.getJSONArray("items");

                                arrayLength = itemsArray.length();

                                if (arrayLength > 0) {

                                    for (int i = 0; i < itemsArray.length(); i++) {

                                        JSONObject itemObj = (JSONObject) itemsArray.get(i);

                                        Item item = new Item(itemObj);

                                        itemsList.add(item);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();

                    } finally {

                        loadingComplete();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            if (!isAdded() || getActivity() == null) {

                Log.e("ERROR", "StreamFragment Not Added to Activity");

                return;
            }

            loadingComplete();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("accountId", Long.toString(App.getInstance().getId()));
            params.put("accessToken", App.getInstance().getAccessToken());
            params.put("itemId", Integer.toString(itemId));
            params.put("language", "en");

            return params;
        }
    };

    App.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);
}

public void loadingComplete() {

    if (arrayLength == LIST_ITEMS) {

        viewMore = true;

    } else {

        viewMore = false;
    }

    itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    if (itemsAdapter.getItemCount() == 0) {

        if (StreamFragment.this.isVisible()) {

            showMessage(getText(R.string.label_empty_list).toString());
        }

    } else {
        hideMessage();
    }
    loadingMore = false;
    mItemsContainer.setRefreshing(false);
}
public void showMessage(String message) {

    mMessage.setText(message);
    mMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

public void hideMessage() {

    mMessage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
}
```

}

Hi I also have another problem. Thanks for solving the first one the below code receives data from categories.java but i want to modify it to only open one category with one category ID like id 5 than receiving category id from categories i want to make it retrieve information from id "5"

package ml.shopnet.market;

public class CategoryFragment extends Fragment implements Constants, SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

```
private static final String STATE_LIST = "State Adapter Data";

RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
TextView mMessage;

SwipeRefreshLayout mItemsContainer;

private ArrayList<Item> itemsList;
private StreamListAdapter itemsAdapter;

private int categoryId = 0;

private int itemId = 0;
private int arrayLength = 0;
private Boolean loadingMore = false;
private Boolean viewMore = false;
private Boolean restore = false;

private String title = "";

int pastVisiblesItems = 0, visibleItemCount = 0, totalItemCount = 0;

public CategoryFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {

        itemsList = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(STATE_LIST);
        itemsAdapter = new StreamListAdapter(getActivity(), itemsList);

        restore = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("restore");
        itemId = savedInstanceState.getInt("itemId");
        categoryId = savedInstanceState.getInt("categoryId");
        title = savedInstanceState.getString("title");

        viewMore = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("viewMore");

    } else {

        itemsList = new ArrayList<Item>();
        itemsAdapter = new StreamListAdapter(getActivity(), itemsList);

        restore = false;
        itemId = 0;
        categoryId = 0;

        Intent i = getActivity().getIntent();

        title = i.getStringExtra("title");
        categoryId = i.getIntExtra("categoryId", 0);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category, container, false);

    mItemsContainer = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.container_items);
    mItemsContainer.setOnRefreshListener(this);

    mMessage = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.message);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    final GridLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), Helper.getGridSpanCount(getActivity()));
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(Helper.getGridSpanCount(getActivity()), dpToPx(10), true));
    mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);

    mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy)
        {
            if(dy > 0) //check for scroll down
            {
                visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                pastVisiblesItems = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                if (!loadingMore)
                {
                    if ((visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount && (viewMore) && !(mItemsContainer.isRefreshing()))
                    {
                        loadingMore = true;
                        Log.e("...", "Last Item Wow !");

                        getItems();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(getActivity(), mRecyclerView, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

            Item i = (Item) itemsList.get(position);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ViewItemActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("itemId", i.getId());
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {
            // ...
        }
    }));

    if (itemsAdapter.getItemCount() == 0) {

        showMessage(getText(R.string.label_empty_list).toString());

    } else {

        hideMessage();
    }

    if (title != null) {

        getActivity().setTitle(title);
    }

    if (!restore) {

        showMessage(getText(R.string.msg_loading_2).toString());

        getItems();
    }

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putBoolean("viewMore", viewMore);
    outState.putBoolean("restore", true);
    outState.putInt("itemId", itemId);
    outState.putInt("categoryId", categoryId);
    outState.putString("title", title);
    outState.putParcelableArrayList(STATE_LIST, itemsList);
}

@Override
public void onRefresh() {

    if (App.getInstance().isConnected()) {

        itemId = 0;
        getItems();

    } else {

        mItemsContainer.setRefreshing(false);
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

public void getItems() {

    mItemsContainer.setRefreshing(true);

    CustomRequest jsonReq = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.POST, METHOD_CATEGORY_GET, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    if (!isAdded() || getActivity() == null) {

                        Log.e("ERROR", "CategoryFragment Not Added to Activity");

                        return;
                    }

                    if (!loadingMore) {

                        itemsList.clear();
                    }

                    try {

                        arrayLength = 0;

                        if (!response.getBoolean("error")) {

                            itemId = response.getInt("itemId");
                            categoryId = response.getInt("categoryId");

                            if (response.has("items")) {

                                JSONArray itemsArray = response.getJSONArray("items");

                                arrayLength = itemsArray.length();

                                if (arrayLength > 0) {

                                    for (int i = 0; i < itemsArray.length(); i++) {

                                        JSONObject itemObj = (JSONObject) itemsArray.get(i);

                                        Item item = new Item(itemObj);

                                        itemsList.add(item);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();

                    } finally {

                        loadingComplete();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            if (!isAdded() || getActivity() == null) {

                Log.e("ERROR", "CategoryFragment Not Added to Activity");

                return;
            }

            loadingComplete();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("accountId", Long.toString(App.getInstance().getId()));
            params.put("accessToken", App.getInstance().getAccessToken());
            params.put("itemId", Long.toString(itemId));
            params.put("categoryId", Integer.toString(categoryId));
            params.put("language", "en");

            return params;
        }
    };

    App.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);
}

public void loadingComplete() {

    if (arrayLength == LIST_ITEMS) {

        viewMore = true;

    } else {

        viewMore = false;
    }

    itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    if (mRecyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() == 0) {

        if (isAdded()) {

            showMessage(getText(R.string.label_empty_list).toString());
        }

    } else {

        hideMessage();
    }

    loadingMore = false;
    mItemsContainer.setRefreshing(false);
}

static class RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

    public interface OnItemClickListener {

        void onItemClick(View view, int position);

        void onItemLongClick(View view, int position);
    }

    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, OnItemClickListener listener) {

        mListener = listener;

        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {

                View childView = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());

                if (childView != null && mListener != null) {

                    mListener.onItemLongClick(childView, recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {

        View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());

        if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {

            mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }
}

/**
 * RecyclerView item decoration - give equal margin around grid item
 */
public class GridSpacingItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    private int spanCount;
    private int spacing;
    private boolean includeEdge;

    public GridSpacingItemDecoration(int spanCount, int spacing, boolean includeEdge) {

        this.spanCount = spanCount;
        this.spacing = spacing;
        this.includeEdge = includeEdge;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {

        int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view); // item position
        int column = position % spanCount; // item column

        if (includeEdge) {

            outRect.left = spacing - column * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
            outRect.right = (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // (column + 1) * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)

            if (position < spanCount) { // top edge

                outRect.top = spacing;
            }

            outRect.bottom = spacing; // item bottom

        } else {

            outRect.left = column * spacing / spanCount; // column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
            outRect.right = spacing - (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - (column + 1) * ((1f /    spanCount) * spacing)

            if (position >= spanCount) {

                outRect.top = spacing; // item top
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Converting dp to pixel
 */
private int dpToPx(int dp) {

    Resources r = getResources();

    return Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, r.getDisplayMetrics()));
}

public void showMessage(String message) {

    mMessage.setText(message);
    mMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

public void hideMessage() {

    mMessage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
}
```

}

Comment: Hello can someone answer my queston

Answer (score 0):

remove `getItems()` from

```
if (!restore) {

    showMessage(getText(R.string.msg_loading_2).toString());

    getItems();
}
```

set click listener to your button then call `getItems()` method

```
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showMessage(getText(R.string.msg_loading_2).toString());
            getItems();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks alot it worked like a charm but i didnt use it with button i used gridview. Thanks alot but Another problem i have now is how to refresh the Fragment. tried using Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i); but it force closes

Comment: no error message it just force close with unfortunately app has stopped

Comment: Open Android studio, open Android Monitor section at bottom, deploy your app to emulator and then copy logcat message.

Comment: it only happens when someone press the reload button like 5 times it stop working with the error. Maybe what in should reload is the fragment and not the MainActivity. . Updated my qustion how can i achieve the solution to the question